# converting seconds from the Epoch into localtime

Tags: r, timezone, epoch, posixct

Suppose I have a few timestamps given as integers (seconds) from the Unix Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00Z).

How do I convert them into the proper date-time in the local timezone? I've been looking at the `as.POSIXct` help page as well as related questions on SO.  It's easy to do in UTC, but for some reason I can't seem able to do it straightforwardly for the local timezone, or for another timezone (BTW, I happen to be in "America/Los_Angeles", or "PST5PDT", which becomes "PST or "PDT" depending of whether daytime savings is in effect at the specified time; so I usually specify the location-based timezone rather than "PST" or "PDT", which are finicky).

Setup for the examples:

```
z <- c(1360527317,1363019665)
```

Quick verification in perl:

```
echo -n 1360527317,1363019665 | perl -ne '
use POSIX /strftime/;
$fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";
for (split /,/) {
  $loc=strftime("$fmt %Z", localtime($_));
  $gmt=strftime("$fmt GMT", gmtime($_));
  print "$_: $loc $gmt\n";
}'
# gives:
1360527317: 2013-02-10 12:15:17 PST 2013-02-10 20:15:17 GMT
1363019665: 2013-03-11 09:34:25 PDT 2013-03-11 16:34:25 GMT
```

First, the obvious (in UTC):

```
as.POSIXct(z, origin='1970-01-01', tz='GMT')
# --> [1] "2013-02-10 20:15:17 GMT" "2013-03-11 16:34:25 GMT"
```

Here are things I tried **that DON'T work**:

```
as.POSIXct(z, origin='1970-01-01')
# --> (wrong) [1] "2013-02-10 20:15:17 PST" "2013-03-11 17:34:25 PDT"

as.POSIXct(z, origin='1970-01-01 00:00:00 Z')
# --> (wrong) [1] "2013-02-10 20:15:17 PST" "2013-03-11 17:34:25 PDT"

as.POSIXct(z, origin='1970-01-01', tz='America/Los_Angeles')
# --> (wrong) [1] "2013-02-10 20:15:17 PST" "2013-03-11 17:34:25 PDT"
```

At my wits' end, here is something that gives me the **correct outcome**:

```
now=Sys.time(); now+(z-unclass(now))
# --> [1] "2013-02-10 12:15:17 PST" "2013-03-11 09:34:25 PDT"
```

And BTW on my system:

```
now=Sys.time()
now
# --> [1] "2013-03-13 18:26:05 PDT"
unclass(now)
# --> [1] 1363224365
```

So it appears that my settings and local timezone are correct.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong with the lines that don't work above?

In the meantime, I'll be using the following trick, hopefully useful to someone else:

```
localtime <- function(t) {
  now = Sys.time();
  return(now+(unclass(t)-unclass(now)))
}
# quick test:
localtime(Sys.time())
# --> [1] "2013-03-13 18:33:40 PDT"
localtime(z)
# --> [1] "2013-02-10 12:15:17 PST" "2013-03-11 09:34:25 PDT"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing a `Date` to `origin` instead of a string

```
as.POSIXct(z, origin=as.Date('1970-01-01'), tz='America/Los_Angeles')
```

Comment: brilliant. works!  However, it looks to me that the documentation is wrong.  See the examples of `?as.POSIXct`.

Comment: furthermore, the fact that there is a difference between `origin=as.Date('1970-01-01')` and `origin='1970-01-01'` and even the very specific `origin='1970-01-01 00:00:00Z'` doesn't inspire me with confidence in the internals of what goes on deep inside...

Comment: @PierreD, this was a bug ([LINK](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14973)). It has been fixed in R-devel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to differentiate between parsing / storing as UTC

```
R> pt <- as.POSIXct(z, origin=as.Date("1970-01-01"))
R> pt
[1] "2013-02-10 14:15:17 CST" "2013-03-11 11:34:25 CDT"
```

Now you can show in whichever TZ you want:

```
R> format(pt, tz="America/Chicago")
[1] "2013-02-10 14:15:17" "2013-03-11 11:34:25"
R> format(pt, tz="America/Los_Angeles")
[1] "2013-02-10 12:15:17" "2013-03-11 09:34:25"
R>
```

Comment: But, those times aren't equal to `"2013-02-10 12:15:17 PST" "2013-03-11 09:34:25 PDT"`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the fact that you can display a time in whatever timezone you choose. That wasn't the problem. The reason why this works was really nailed by @GSee: the key is use `origin=as.Date('1970-01-01')` and not `origin='1970-01-01'` as the help page wrongly shows. The former works, the latter doesn't.